# How to create a sequence in a specific format in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to automatically generate an unique entity field in Postgresql in following format:

"ССDDD" where "C" is a character and "D" is a digit.

For example "FG1752" or "HK9273".
How can this be implemented?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it just to produce a non obvious numeric identifier? If so you could use something like [hashids](https://hashids.org/) to accomplish this more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way in `mysql` :

```
SELECT concat(char(floor(rand() *(90-65+1)+65)), 
       char(floor(rand() *(90-65+1)+65)), 
       lpad(floor(rand() *(10000)),4,0) 
) RandomAlphanumeric
```

in `postgresql`:

```
SELECT concat(chr(floor(random() *(90-65+1)+65)::int), 
       chr(floor(random() *(90-65+1)+65)::int), 
       lpad(floor(random() *(10000))::varchar(4),4,'0') 
) RandomAlphanumeric
```

I'm producing a random number between 65 and 90 which are ascii code for A to Z